# SQL table column comments in view column comments

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I have a table with column comments explaining the purpose for each column. I know I can view these column comments by querying all_col_comments.

But I want to create a view based on this table, and I want the columns in this view to inherit the column comments from the original table.

```
select comm.table_name, comm.column_name, comm.comments   
from all_col_comments comm
join all_tab_cols cols on comm.table_name=cols.table_name and comm.owner=cols.owner and comm.column_name=cols.column_name
where comm.owner = :OWNER
and comm.table_name = 'PERSON'
order by comm.table_name, cols.column_id;
```

The results are:

```
TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME COMMENTS
PERSON      PERS_ID     PERS_ID is the identifier of a person.
PERSON      LANG_ID     LANG_ID identifies the person's language.
```

Now, if I make a view based on this table I have to add the comments manually. The best way I found (which is a terrible way) is to hard-code this into the create view statement. There has to be a better way.

Comment: Why do you have a separate table for column comments, when Oracle provides `all_col_comments`?  Or, am I totally misunderstanding your question?

Comment: " view based on this table" you mean "Create or Replace view V_Person AS Select * from Person" ?
Why not simply copy and paste the comments from the ddl script of your table and search and replace Person by V_person? or am i understanding somethin wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table person (id number, col1 varchar2(50 char));
comment on column person.id is 'it is ID';
comment on column person.col1 is 'it is COL1';

create or replace view v_person as select id from person;
```

You may try this query:

```
select ud.name view_name, 
       ud.referenced_name based_tab,
       vcols.column_name,
       nvl(vcom.comments, tcom.comments) comments
from all_dependencies ud
join all_tab_columns vcols on vcols.table_name = ud.name and vcols.owner=ud.owner
left join all_tab_columns tcols on tcols.table_name = ud.referenced_name and vcols.column_name = tcols.column_name and tcols.owner=ud.owner
left join all_col_comments tcom on ud.referenced_name = tcom.table_name and tcols.column_name = tcom.column_name and tcom.owner=ud.owner
left join all_col_comments vcom on ud.name = vcom.table_name and vcols.column_name = vcom.column_name and vcom.owner=ud.owner
where ud.name = 'V_PERSON' 
  and ud.type = 'VIEW' 
  and ud.referenced_type = 'TABLE';
```

1. Use `all_dependencies` to find the table(s) on which the view is based
2. Join it with `all_tab_columns` twice to find the information about view columns and table columns (**this query will work if a view has the same column names as the underlying table**)
3. Left join with `all_col_comments` twice to find view and table column comments

Comment: I had to add a bit to this query to include the OWNER column in each join, since a view with this name existed in two schema's. Other than that, worked like a charm!